# Convergence Range of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)^2}$$

**My Attempt**: I realize that $-1 \leq \sin(2n-1) \leq 1$. If I take the absolute value I can create the inequality:

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} | \frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)^2}| \leq (1)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(2n-1)^2}$$

I know $(1)$ will converge regardless of what $x$ is which makes the original series converge as well. Hence, the range of convergence would be $-\infty <x <\infty$ Is this correct, and if not could someone provide a better justification?

Comment: I would read this as $\sin((2n - 1)x)$, then that estimate might not hold, (namely for negative $x$) but you'll reach the same conclusion comparing to $\displaystyle \frac 1 {(2n - 1)^2}$, and noting that absolute convergence implies usual convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I support *George Coote*'s comment: it should be $\sin[(2n-1)x]$ rather than $[\sin(2n-1)]x$. However, the crucial estimation works regardless of this issue. In fact
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\left|\frac{\sin[(2n-1)x]}{(2n-1)^2}\right|=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{|\sin[(2n-1)x]|}{(2n-1)^2}\leqslant\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{(2n-1)^2}$$
Thus, the series converges absolutely independent of the actual value of $x$ and therefore the radius of convergence (assuming $x$ is real) is in fact the entire real line.

Answer (score 0):

You proved that the series converges absolutely, therefore it converges (, independently of $x$). Your justification is correct.